# SQLite: how to organize my data base

Tags: android, mysql, database, organization

I am having a simple android app and want to know the best way to organize my database tables (mysql).
The idea of the app is a list of categories then the user presses on one of these categories and he gets another list of items and when he clicks on one of them, he gets details about it.

For example, the first list (countries) has (UK, US, China, Japan, and other countries)

You click on US, you get another list (states) has (California, NY, Arizona,...)

You click on California, you get its details (population, area, capital)

Same thing would happen if you click UK then London...

So, how should I arrange my data, should I make:

1. one table for countries and another table for each country,
2. only one big table for all states and it will have a column to say which country does it belong to.
3. any other suggestion?

Comment: I would suggest the 2. option, querying one table should be more efficient in this case

Comment: Definitely 3 tables, country, state, details.

Answer (score 1):

You should make the 3 table 1 for countries and another for states and another for details.

**Reason:**

1. By this there will not be redundant data and it follows the normalization rules.
2. you will get the only data which you want not other than that.

You can use the form submit or ajax to get the data from the tables.

**EDITED:**

As per asked by IAM the data in the database as you will store the data of details corresponding of states and then states corresponding of countries then there you will enter the countries name multiple times in a single column for each states. Then such the data of countries and states will be multiple time in database and your database will be heavy.

Comment: what redundant data? example? may be only population and area

Answer (score 1):

Try something like the following.. and go from there..

`create table countries (
  id int(11) not null auto_increment,
  name varchar(255) not null,
  primary key (id)
);`

create table states (
  id int(11) not null auto_increment,
  name varchar(255) not null,
  country_id int(11) not null,
  primary key (id)
  constraint foreign key (country_id) references countries(id) on delete cascade
);

create table properties (
  name varchar(255) not null,
  primary key (name)
);

create table state_properties (
  id int(11) not null auto_increment,
  property varchar(255) not null,
  state_id int(11) not null,
  primary key(id),
  constraint foreign key (property) references properties(property) on delete cascade,
  constraint foreign key (state_id) references states(id) on delete cascade
);

edited: typo

Comment: Thanks Ilan, I just wanna understand why you put the properties table? what is it for?

Comment: It's my personal preference.  Better to normalize on properties and have a foreign key constraint then to rely on strings.. You can optionally use the enum type that some db vendors support.. I keep switching db's so I forget which ones support enum.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the information is stored as JSON or XML blobs, you should have TWO tables.  Not one or three.  Build from the ground up.

```
CREATE TABLE locale (locID int PRIMARY KEY, data BLOB )

CREATE TABLE localGrouping (
    groupID int PRIMARY KEY,
    groupName varchar(255),
    parentGroup int NULL,
    locID int NULL
)
```

You mentioned that want to have a list of countries, and then drill down to cities or states.  Which is all find and dandy, but what happens if you want to include stats at the state level above the city?  Or the city level above the neighborhood?

A proper database normalization, as in any proper programming, follows the "Zero One Infinity" rule.  Especially when it comes to hierarchical data sets.

(Of course, feel free to add however many tables are apporopriate from `LOCALE` on down.  But unless you're going to be running comparative indexes on a locale's properties, a serialized data object should be fine.)